# About anything vs For anything

Tags: american-english

May I be educated on which of the two is correct:

```
Create a webpage about anything

Create a webpage for anything
```

Comment: Hi elaisha! It depends on the context. Usually 'about' would be used. But if these webpages are charitable, or are concerned with supporting or  promoting something, then 'for' might be more appropriate.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian I see. That makes sense. Thanks.